# When I echo something inside my controller function jquery error is showing

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

Can Any One Please Help Me Out:

This is my controller function:

```
function postShareNetwork(){

            $input   = Input::all();
            $userIds =  $input['users'];
            $sender = $this->contRepo->getUserByID($this->getCurrentUser());
            $subscriber = array();
            $filter['notifyon_share_folder'] = 1;
            $receievers = $this->contRepo->getContactByEmailSetting((array)$userIds, $filter);

            $msg = "Document has been shared successfully.";
            if(!empty($input['folder'])) {
                $msg = "Folder has been shared successfully.";
            }

            if(empty($receievers)) {
                return Response::json([
                    'success' => true,
                    'errors' => array($msg)
                ]);
            }

            $folder = \Resource::find($input['folder']);


            if(!empty($input['folder'])){
                $resourceId = $folder->id;
                $view = 'network::emails.folder-emailed';
                $folderName = $folder->display_name;
            }elseif ( !empty($input['doc'])) {
                $doc = $this->resRepo->getFile($input['doc'])[0];
                $resourceId = $doc->id;
                $fileName = $doc->display_name;
                $view = 'network::emails.shared-network-doc';
                $subject = 'file shared';
            }

            $actAfter =  [
                \TempAction::TYPE_ADD_COLLEAGUE => [
                    'act_type' => 'after_login',
                    'args' => [
                        'sender' => $this->getCurrentUser()
                    ]
                ],
                \TempAction::TYPE_NETWORK_SHARE => [

                    'act_type' => 'after_login',
                    'args' => [
                        'sender' => $this->getCurrentUser(),
                        'resourceId' => $resourceId
                    ]
                ]
            ];

            foreach ($receievers as $user) {
                /*$token = Crypt::encrypt($resourceId.'_'.$user->id.'_'.$this->getCurrentUser());*/

                $actParams = [
                    'receiver'=> $user->email,
                    'after'   => $actAfter
                ];

                $jsonEncoded = json_encode($actParams);
                $linkToken = Crypt::encrypt($jsonEncoded);

                //\URL::route('shared-network-resource', $token);
                $link  = route('temp-email-link', ['token' => $linkToken]);
                if ( !empty($input['doc'])) {
                    $subject = $fileName .' Shared by: '.$sender[0]->getName();
                }else{
                    $subject = $user->getName() . ' Join My KShare Network';
                }

                $data = [
                    'email'       => $user->email,
                    'subject'     => $subject,
                    'name'        => $user->getName(),
                    'sender_f_name' => $sender[0]->profile->first_name,
                    'sender_l_name' => $sender[0]->profile->last_name,
                    'sender_name' => $sender[0]->getName(),
                    'sender_email'=> $sender[0]->email,
                    'share_link'  => $link,
                    'email_message' => $subject,
                    'file_name'     => isset($fileName) ? $fileName : null,
                    'folder_name' => isset($folderName) ? $folderName : null
                ];

                \Mail::queue($view, $data, function($messages) use ($data){ 
                    $messages->to($data['email'], $data['name'])
                        ->subject($data['subject'] );
                });

            }

            return Response::json([
                'success' => true,
                'errors' => array($msg)
            ]);

    }
```

And the jquery when form submit is given below:

```
$modelPopup.find('#form-add-email').on('submit', function(){

        var $form = $(this),
        $selUsers = $listUsers.filter(':checked');

        // validate form to select at least one user.
        if($selUsers.length == 0){
            alert("Please select at least one user");
            return false;
        }

        // post data.
        $.ajax({
            url: $form.attr('action'),
            type: "POST",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#loading').show();
            },
            error: function(jq,status,message) {
                $('#loading').hide();
                $msg ="<p class='msg msg_unsuccess'>"+ 'A jQuery error has occurred. Status: ' + status + ' - Message: ' + message + '</p>';
                $('.msg_wrapper').html($msg);
                $('.msg_wrapper p.msg').delay(3000).fadeOut();
            }
        }).done(function(response) {
            $('#loading').hide();
            if (response.success==true) {
                var msg = "<p class='msg msg_success'>"+response.errors+"</p>";
                $modelPopup.find('.close').click();
                $('.msg_wrapper').html(msg);
            }
            if (response.success==false) {
                var msg = "<p class='msg msg_unsuccess'>"+response.errors+"</p>";
                $('#share_via_mail .msg_wrapper').html(msg);
                $('.msg_wrapper').html(msg);
            }
            $('.msg_wrapper p.msg').delay(3000).fadeOut();
            $('.btn').removeClass('no_loader');
                $('.reset_loader').addClass('no_loader');
        });

        return false;
    });
```

The problem is that when i simply echo the name or any text or do any thing inside the function it is throwing jquery error so I didn't find where I am wrong please help me out for this

Comment: This is expected behaviour as you're returning JSON in your controller. If you echo anything else then it will result in the response format NOT being valid JSON - hence the deserialiser jQuery uses will throw an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are expecting from server valid JSON(like `{"name":"Some Name"}`.

Now when you echo something, it becomes like this `Echoed text{"name":"Some Name"}` or just `Echoed Text` and that is not valid JSON leading to failed Ajax request.

You can remove `dataType: "json"` while testing and echoing.

Either way in console network tab you will always see server response (even when JSON is not valid)

Comment: Thanks for your reply,I removed but still not working getting jquery error

Comment: @user2110253 What response text and status (from network tab) you get?

Comment: 500 internal error:   Accept:text/plain, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:87
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Host:localhost:8000
Origin:http://localhost:8000
Referer:http://localhost:8000/f/287/view
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/48.0.2564.116 Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest

Comment: @user2110253 Well than fix this error first. Because if you return not 200 status code, JS will assume there was an error on server side and fall to `error` instead of `success`